# What is a synonym for "jack of all trades, master of none"?

Tags: synonyms, figures-of-speech

What is a synonym of *jack of all trades, master of none*?

I want to differentiate it from a *generalist* (might have deep knowledge about everything)?

On the same note, is there a better way to say *jack of all trades, master of all*?

Comment: How about a specialist hyphen generalist (specialist-generalist)?  Apropos of nothing:  the phrase "triple threat"  can mean a person who can act, direct, and write equally well.  So I guess you could call someone a quadruple threat if s/he is a master of four things, a quintuple threat if a master of five, a sextuple threat a master of six, etc.

Comment: For real philologists, "How many languages do you know?" is a difficult question that involves a counting problem. There are languages you know well, then it transitions to a long tail, and where you draw the line is not absolutely straightforward. Calling someone an n-tuple threat becomes hazier for higher values of n.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A **polymath** is a person of encyclopedic learning.

A **Renaissance Man** is a person whose expertise spans a significant number of different subject areas.

A person who is a jack of all trades, but a master of *none* might be called a **dabbler**.

Comment: Being a Polymath and Renaissance Man is the same thing. The later used to indicate a _male_ polymath. Correct answer nevertheless.

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher - I agree, the terms are very tightly related.  However, I think many people consider _polymath_ to be based on knowledge whereas _Renaissance Man_ (or woman) implies skills (such as artistic ability) which go beyond intellectual abilities.

Comment: To call someone a polymath or Renaissance Man, however, is to indicate proficiency in a variety of fields, in which a jack of all trades would merely dabble.

Comment: A 'Jack of all trades' is "one who has a smattering of several branches of knowledge." and is not a term related to a polymath or "a person whose expertise spans a significant number of different subject areas; such a person is known to draw on complex bodies of knowledge to solve specific problems."

Answer (score 12):

A **dilettante** is a person who dabbles in a variety of pursuits but is not dedicated to any particular one.

A sage, a savant, a genius, an expert, a diviner, an Olympian, a guru, a god (small G)--all describe a multi-talented person who is exceedingly capable in seemingly everything and is "master of *all*."  A dilettante, on the other hand, is a "master of *none*."

The phrase you refer to, by the way, is a rhetorical figure called *antithesis*, an expression of contrasting elements.  In "Jack of all trades, master of none," we have the following contrasts:  Jack (a common name and common nickname for John) and master; all and none; trades (plural--many) and trade (implied singular--or one).

Answer (score 7):

I have seen the use of "factotum"  to replace "jack of all trades".  I had to look it up the first time I read it.

Answer (score 7):

A person with several skills may be said to be a [**generalist**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalist).

Comment: Your link is blocked but Wikipedia list "Generalist may refer to: a person with a wide array of knowledge, the opposite of which is a specialist."   This is indeed exactly what a 'Jack of all trades' denotes

Comment: @ThirdNews : Thanks. I've updated the link. It now directs to the Wiki page.

Answer (score 4):

try

- bricoleur
- Feynmanesque
- versatile

Comment: If you add dictionary references to each of these it would be a much better answer. There are a number of ways to do this: [see markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).