# Word that means generally knowledgeable?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that means knowing about lots of different things, across different fields of study. The idea behind Renaissance man. This might be a noun or an adjective.

> Mrs. Jones is (a) ____________. Although she teaches Spanish, she can tutor any student at our school in any subject.

Comment: You can also consider *learned man/woman*.

Comment: polymath is the better answer

Comment: Very closely related: [What is a synonym for “jack of all trades, master of none”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/108536/177853) (and all its long line of duplicates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mrs. Jones is very **erudite**. Although she teaches Spanish, she can tutor any student at our school in any subject.

> Having or showing great knowledge or learning

[TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/erudite)

Answer (score 4):

The term [**polymath**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymath) is very similar to *Renaissance man*. They're almost synonymous. Translated from Greek, *polymath* literally means *having learned much*. Generally, a polymath is a person of wide knowledge or learning. Filling in the blank in your example sentence:

> Mrs. Jones is **a real polymath**. Although she teaches Spanish, she can tutor any student at our school in any subject.

I think that the term *erudite* is a good word to describe someone who is well-read and knows a lot of things in general, but not necessarily someone who is an expert in a variety of different subjects to the extent that they can actually teach them.